# How to get Jackson to convert a JSONObject as string in the payload?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I have a POJO class which I use to serialise and deserialise between JSON messages and the POJO object for use within my Java code. In the POJO class, there is a field called `requestMessage` which contains a string of JSON. When the payload is sent between the services, this field is literally just a string.

For example, this is how the payload would look:

```
{
   "name": "John Smith",
   "status": true,
   "requestMessage": "{\"id\": \"some-id\", \"timestamp\": \"2019-11-30\"}"
}
```

To cater for this field, I created an attribute `requestMessage` in my POJO class and made the type as `JSONObject`, which is a type from the `org.json` package. I was thinking this kind of make sense because in case I need to use it in my code, I could easily access the information as a `JSONObject`. I've something like this in my POJO class:

```
public class Message {
    private String name;
    private boolean status;
    private JSONObject requestMessage;

    @JsonCreator
    public Message(
            @JsonProperty("name") String name,
            @JsonProperty("status") boolean status,
            @JsonProperty("requestMessage") JSONObject requestMessage
    ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.status = status;
        this.requestMessage = requestMessage;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public JSONObject getRequestMessage() {
        return requestMessage;
    }

    public void setRequestMessage(JSONObject requestMessage) {
        this.requestMessage = requestMessage;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Message{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", status=" + status +
                ", requestMessage=" + requestMessage +
                '}';
    }
}
```

However, it seems Jackson wasn't able to convert it as a string properly when sending out the message. The `requestMessage` field is always converted into a string as an empty `{}` object in the payload.

How can I get Jackson to convert and map the `requestMessage` attribute in the `Message` POJO class correctly as a string when it's sending out the payload?

Comment: perhaps use jackson's own `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode`; it's smart to serialize its own types directly

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino If I were to use `JsonNode` instead, how do I create the `Message` POJO object? With `JSONObject`, I could do `new JSONObject("{\"id\": \"some-id\", \"timestamp\": \"2019-11-30\"}")`. But I can't do this with `JsonNode`.

Comment: What about creating custom deserializer to wrap it into a POJO?

Comment: @Carven use `ObjectMapper` class; https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readTree(java.lang.String)

Comment: Why not just declare `requestMessage` to be a `String`? You can just operate it as a JSON object with `Jackson`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Jackson to serialize the `JSONObject` field using its `toString` method, like this:

```java
public static class Message {
    private String name;
    private boolean status;
    @JsonSerialize(using=ToStringSerializer.class)
    private JSONObject requestMessage;
    // ...
}
```

Deserialization was working because Jackson defaults to use a constructor that takes a `String` parameter for deserialization. `JSONObject` has one, so it got deserialized. I would have expected, for consistency, that `toString` was used on serialization, but it doesn't. I imagine there must be a good design reason behind it.

That being said, I don't understand why you try to use `JSONObject` from `json.org` if you are already using Jackson. I would stick to `JSONObject`'s equivalent in Jackson, which I guess is `JsonNode`, as suggested by [Coderino Javarino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3787777/coderino-javarino).